# Insert a new column after every 7 columns with a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 4000 records that keeps on updating new data. The column headers are Employee Name, Project, Activity, 06/29/2013, 06/30/2013... etc. These are individual dates starting from October of last year to this week and each of these columns contains numeric values. I'm trying to modify this week-wise. So if Sunday is considered as the 7th day of a week, then I want to subtract the values from this week's Sunday with the last week's Sunday. And I'd want it to continue doing that for the rest of the columns since the dates will keep on updating so it's going to be taxing to do it manually.

[image: A rough sketch of what I want. Hope it's understandable..]

FYI I'm using Excel 2013.

I know how to perform basic operations but this one is beyond my understanding so any help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub insert_column_after_interval_7()
For colx = 7 To 200 Step 8
Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next
End Sub
```

I have specified the range as 200 but the data might exceed later on. So how do I modify it without giving any specific range?

Comment: to do this without VBA code, (which is what macros use in the background) you'd have to do this manually as there is no excel function for looping (making a function run more than once) so you could record a macro of you inserting a column, and writting the formula, but you'd have to run it however many times for each week. To do this in VBA you'd use a loop, starting at the first sunday, inserting a column, inserting a function, then moving 7 cells to the right, and repeating. if you don't know VBA at all, you'll need to hire someone who does as nobody is going to code a whole macro for you.

Comment: having said all that, if you do know VBA, give it a shot, and if you get stuck, post the code you used, and what happened when you tried that, and we'll help you through that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Don't know much about VBA though. I actually found another way around it. But I do have a doubt about inserting new columns after every 7th interval.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something along the lines of this:

```
Sub insert_column_after_interval_7()

dim iLastCol as integer

    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' same as CTRL+RIGHT ARROW 

    For colx = 7 To iLastCol Step 8
        Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next

End Sub
```

of course, as you are likely adding more than 8 columns, you might be better off with a `DO WHILE` loop

Comment: this is how you process all rows / columns, by finding the last row / column and using that instead of a static number like 200. although, i find `Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column` to work a bit better at finding the last column. it can be adapted like: `Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row` to find the last row as well.